# developing extensions for AIR: is it possible to start on Windows

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I need to develop small AIR extension for iOS. here's the question: is it possible to start it on Windows (and to debug with AIR built-in simulator)? Or I need MAC OS and iPad from the very beginning?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targeting iOS, the only way to make sure it *really* works on an iOS device is testing it on an iOS device. The AIR device emulator let me do things that weren't actually allowed on iOS, like loading another swf with assets at runtime. The emulator didn't complain but a compiled version run on my iPod did.

Also, you can't judge performance on an emulator because your computer will be a lot more powerful than an actual device.

The emulator may be enough for a simple 'hello world' project to get you started, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can write/debug on any platform but if you need to access data/IO devices for specific device/OS than you need to debug on the respective device/OS for witch you build the application